# new activity not starting (app has stopped)

Tags: java, android

I want to open a new activity by clicking on `cardview(item)` in Recyclerview. But my new activity is unable to start and application has stopped pops up

My adapter class is

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<Contacts> listitems;
private Context context;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(Contacts item);
}

public MyAdapter(List<Contacts> listitems, Context context) {
    this.listitems = listitems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contacts c = listitems.get(position);

    holder.t1.setText(c.getName());
    holder.t2.setText(c.getNumber());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listitems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView t1,t2;
    public ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        t1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        t2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context,Details.class));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post the error that you are receiving in your android monitor.

Comment: android monitor doesnt showing any errors just app is crashing as i click on item

Comment: Why are you using itemview.setOnClickListener?  You can give id to your root layout and perform on click listener on it

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context,Details.class));
```

with

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,Details.class));
```

Comment: i did as you said but it didnt help :(

Comment: is it showing some error or just crashing the application if it is just crashing ?

Comment: then error is in Details.class not in this class

Comment: not showing any error just crashing :(

Comment: i just found out , i did not register the new class and its layout (new activity) in manifest 
btw thanks :)

Comment: Check whether the activity you are opening is defined in manifest file
Also post error log showing in Android Monitor

Answer (score 0):

you are using recycler view then you can use this in your activity not in adapter

```
recyclerview.onaddOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
      Activity_name.startActivity(new Intent(context,Details.class));
    }
}));
```

Comment: you have to remove onclicklistener from the adapter

Comment: Have you defined activity in manifest file, if defined then share the error logs